Vertex Weight Proximity - Weight gradient shape difference
Hello Blender experts,
I am following a YouTube tutorial from a creator: Dobpen
Here I am lost about managing the weight gradient shape while the target object passes through the main obejct like below.
The first image is my WIP and another one is from an example that I am following..


Like the images above from the weight paint mode, I follow more or less the same setting and geometry values from the tutorial but my gradient shows a radial shape on X and Y axes, thus the blue area doesn't reach out to the endpoint of both sides. By contrast, the example shows a linear flow like wrapping around the object on the X axis.
In order to fix this, I tried

Handling the lowest and highest values isn't helpful..
Changing the shape or ratio of the target object doesn't work as well..

Is there anyone knowing to solve the topic that I am dealing with?
Thank you for sharing your comments or experience in advance.
Minsung

Looks like you are using an empty (No vertices, no faces kind of object) and on the second image it looks like it's using a cube (with vertices and faces) but in wireframe

Thank you Emir, It was true that I used empty object instead of a mesh cube. It seems it is related to the scale and ratio of the target object. Thanks to you, I have learned something today!
